# Get shared album with Google Photos api by share key

Tags: javascript, rest, api, share, photo

the Google Api is really easy to use when I want to show the albums and photos of the user who is currently using my site. But now I have another plan. I would like to show photos from my own Google Photos album to all visitors of my website. Share my own album, so to say, but access it via REST api and integrate it into my website via JavaScript. Is something like this even possible? Up to now I didn't find any information about this on the internet, except with the (old) Picasa Api.

Thank you guys for some information!

Regards
artzuk